# How can I shrink a volume

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

In my desktop all hard disk is taken as Ubuntu partition. I, want to shrink this by at least 50 GB to make another partition, to keep my personal data.

This is an image of my partitions

[image]

How can I shrink this partition and create a new one?

Comment: install gparted using `sudo apt-get install gparted` for more help see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions and this also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition

Answer (score 2):

Get the gParted live dvd from http://gparted.org/livecd.php

Burn it to a disk like you would with a normal Ubuntu installation.

Boot from it and you get a gParted session where all your normal disks are not mounted so you can manipulate them (and shrinking is one of those options).

Mind you: always make a backup of important files before messing with partitions.